# Возврат функции по ссылке

Tags: php

Зачем использовать 2 раза знак `&`?

**Приведу пример:**

```
function &func() /// Тут
{
     static $static = 0;
     $static++;
     return $static;
}
$var1 = &func(); /// Тут
echo "var1:", $var1; // 1
func();
func();
echo "var1:", $var1; // 3
```

В документации про это ничего не написано! Логичнее было бы писать `return &$static`

И еще вопрос, а что если мы не напишем амперсанд в указании функции?

И что также будет если мы напишем амперсанд в указании функции, но не напишем в присвоении?

Comment: У переменной если не будет ссылки(`&`), то значение не будет обновляться. Также и с функцией - всегда будет `1`.

Comment: @mix Я не понял ничего, изъясняйтесь понятнее, желательно с примерами, это же не русский язык

Comment: знак `&` называется "ссылкой"

Comment: @mix ага про это мы знаем =)

Comment: значит плохо знаете, раз спрашиваете. Самый ясный пример перед вами, поэкспериментируйте и поймете потребность 2-ух знаком амперсанда.

Comment: вы значит не поняли вопроса =)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то, нет, в документации об этом написано (и вполне подробно и ясно, на мой взгляд): http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php
Почему? Такой синтаксис придумали. Вероятно, вы раньше писали на C или C++, если он вас смущает. Что ж, php - не C, ссылки в нем работают совсем по-другому. Как именно - лучше всего прочитать, опять же, в документации.

> а что если мы не напишем амперсанд в указании функции?

То будет возвращение не по ссылке, а по значению. Знак амперсанда - единственное и достаточно условие для обозначения, что функция должна возвращать "по ссылке". В конструкции "return" никакие амперсанды не нужны.

> И что также будет если мы напишем амперсанд в указании функции, но не напишем в присвоении?

Это валидная конструкция языка. Вы присвоите переменной значение. Собственно, в данном случае амперсанд относится скорее к присвоению, чем к функции. С таким же успехом можно написать, к примеру, $var =& $var2; - сделать, чтоб

Comment: P.S. Самый лучший способ проверить "а что если" - написать тестовый пример и выполнить его :)

Comment: Ну если в каком либо месте нет амперсанда  то не будет линковки по ссылке, мне просто интересно будет ли код внутри работать по-другому если к примеру я просто напишу амперсанд перед именем функции в объявлении...это будет тоже самое что и функция без амперсанда?

Comment: Внутри функции всё будет работать абсолютно так же, как и при возврате по значению. Единственное исключение - если функция декларирована с амперсандом, то в return обязательно должно быть выражение, допускающее обращение по ссылке (переменная, доступ к переменной-массиву, вызов другой функции с возвратом по значению и т.д.). Вернуть ссылку на константу, к примеру, нельзя (напрямую).

Comment: Ключевые различия будут не при исполнении функции, а при использовании результата ее выполнения.

Comment: Выражения нельзя передать по ссылке!

Comment: @MaximPro не правда. Некоторые типы выражений (например, перечисленные мною выше) - очень даже можно. По крайней мере, в свежих версиях php. Нельзя передавать по ссылке только те выражения, в которых нельзя отследить ссылку на результат (например, `$a + $b`). В документации эти вопросы очень хорошо освещены.

Comment: Передать по ссылке можно только переменную (а переменная может вмещать в себя все что угодно), или приведите код который бы являлся выражением и это передавалось бы по ссылке

Comment: Привожу: `$a =& $b[0];`. Что самое смешное - один из примеров есть в описании вашего вопроса - переменной var1 по ссылке присваивается результат выполнения "ссылочной" функции, а это есть ничто иное, как выражение. Для return действуют те же правила, что и для присвоения. Если остались вопросы - можете писать мне на y.sitnikoff@gmail.com, а то система мне уже намекает, что грешно слишком много общаться в комментах :) Там же могу привести более обширные примеры, которые можно выполнить и воочию убедиться.

Comment: Так это переменная по факту =)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46606/discussion-between-maximpro-and-yury-sitnikov).